# Power consumption of audio over OTG cable

Tags: battery-life, usb-on-the-go

I recently found that if I connect a USB pair of speaker/microphone using OTG cable to a phone, it becomes the audio device by default, and I can actually play audio over that. It happens that the USB headset has much better quality than the earplug ones that I connect over audio connector.

My question is, if I use this OTG-USB-Headset trick, will it drains the battery faster than just having my earplugs connected on the audio connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have tried now is known for long as you can see from Google search - [connecting usb headset to usb on the go](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=connecting+usb+headset+to+usb+on+the+go&oq=c&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i65l2j69i60j5.1461j0j4&client=ms-android-huawei&sourceid=chrome-)

- [USB on the go](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) wiki (see *Protocols* section) talks of *ADP and SRP* protocols relevant to your usage, to conserve on the mobile battery power - translated what it means is that power is drawn from the mobile battery and not from the USB headset, even if it has battery source

> .... will I drain my battery faster than just having my earplugs connected on the audio connector ?

Depends on the power rating of your USB headset- *if it is more than the earplugs provided by the phone (common case), then yes it will drain faster*

**Additional Information**

- See [avs forum](http://www.avsforum.com/forum/173-2-channel-audio/1393599-enable-usb-audio-any-android-4-0-smartphone-tablet-10.html#/forumsite/3207/topics/1393599?page=10&postid=28879001) for more insight for audio use case
- [Maxim integrated](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1822) application notes for electrical details